# WiX feature is installed when explicitly told not to

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wix

I have two different WiX features that behave differently for some reason. I'm using WiX 3.14.

The first feature is selected by default in the installation process. It can be deselected or selected by the user. If it is selected, it will be installed, if it is deselected, it will not be installed. All is well.

The second feature has two child features. The first child features is selected by default, and the second child feature is deselected by default. Both the child nodes and the parent can be selected or deselected by the user. No matter what the select status is of any of the nodes, in any combination, all of it is always installed. Do I need to do something extra here to make it not install when it is deselected?

```
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyProduct" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" Absent="disallow"
             Description="Support for my fantastic product.">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponentFeature2_1" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponentFeature2_2" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Shortcuts" />
    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="Feature1" Title="My first feature" Level="1"
             Description="Some nice feature.">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="CompFeature1"/>
    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="Feature2" Title="My second feature" Level="1" Display="expand"
             Description="This node has child nodes.">
      <Feature Id="Feature2_1" Title="The first part of my second feature." Level="1"
             Description="This is selected by default.">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponentFeature2_1"/>
      </Feature>
      <Feature Id="Feature2_2" Title="The second part of my second feature." Level="32767"
             Description="This is deselected by default.">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponentFeature2_2"/>
      </Feature>
    </Feature>
```

With respective components:

```
    <ComponentGroup Id="CompFeature1" Directory="InstallDirFeature1">
      <Component Id="CompFeature1" Guid="<guid>">
        <File Id="Feature1App" Name="$(var.Feature1App.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.Feature1App.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <Shortcut Id="SCFeature1App" Icon="ICfeature1.exe" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Feature 1 App" Description="Cool." Show="normal" Advertise="yes">
          <Icon Id="ICfeature1.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Feature1App.TargetPath)"/>
        </Shortcut>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponentFeature2_1" Directory="InstallDirFeature2_1>
      <Component Id="CompFeature2_1" Guid="<guid>">
        <File Id="Feature2_1App" Name="$(var.Feature2_1App.TargetName).exe" Source="$(var.Feature2_1App.ProjectDir)bin\publish\win-x64\$(var.Feature2_1App.TargetName).exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <Shortcut Id="SCFeature2_1App" Icon="ICfeature2.exe" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Feature 2 App" Description="Sweet." Show="normal" Advertise="yes">
          <Icon Id="ICfeature2.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Feature2_1App.TargetPath)"/>
        </Shortcut>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponentFeature2_2" Directory="InstallDirFeature2_2">
      <Component Id="CompFeature2_2" Guid="<guid>">
          <File Id="Feature2_2App" Name="$(var.Feature2_2App.TargetName).exe" Source="$(var.Feature2_2App.ProjectDir)bin\publish\win-x86\$(var.Feature2_2App.TargetName).exe" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <ComponentGroup Id="Shortcuts" Directory="ProgramMenuDir">
      <Component Id="ProgramMenuShortcut" Guid="<guid>">
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\<MyCompany>\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first feature tag contains references to the component groups of feature 2.1 and 2.2 that are not needed. When removed, the features are no longer installed when deselected.